# Why other textboxes are also getting mask in datagridview control?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have a datagrid view control. Now I have two textbox columns to it. Out of which the first I have set to Password. The problem is that whenever, I try to edit something in the other textbox, it is equally getting display in masked text's.How to avoid this?

My code is as under

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{


   if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
  {
      TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
      if (tb != null)
      {
          tb.PasswordChar = '*';
      }
  } 
}

private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.Value != null)
   {

     e.Value = new string('*', e.Value.ToString().Length);

   }
}
```

Comment: could help you .. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?554744-RESOLVED-2008-Datagridview-Password-Column-Cellformatting

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
  {

        TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
        if (tb != null)
        {
           if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
           {
              tb.PasswordChar = '*';
           }
           else
           {
              tb.PasswordChar = (char)0;
           }
     } 
  }
```

the explanation will come shortly. i just can say for now that the `tb.PasswordChar` is '*' for all the `textBox`. still checking why

found the explanation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing.aspx). basically "The DataGridView control hosts one editing control at a time" and therefor changing the `PasswordChar` property for one cell is editing it for the entire `DataGrid`.
 That was very interesting studying this. thanks